# Unable to access web app deployed on remote JBoss

Tags: jboss

We have purchased a Virtual Private Server(VPS) and installed JBoss EAP 7.0.0 on it. We have deployed our application on this VPS JBoss. I am able to access our application on the VPS using "https://localhost:port-number/Our-Application".

However, when I try to access the app from my laptop using the VPS IP address I get "This site can’t be reached "VPS IP address" took too long to respond ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT". I get the same problem if I try to access http://VPS-IP-Address:8080.

Address wild card for the public interface is set to "Any Address". I tried setting public interface Inet Address to ${jboss.bind.address.management:VPS IP address}/${jboss.bind.address.management:0.0.0.0} it didn't work. I tried starting the JBoss using standalone.bat -b 0.0.0.0  and standalone.bat -b "VPS IP address" it didn't work.

Setting public interface Inet Address to ${jboss.bind.address.public:VPS IP address}/${jboss.bind.address.public:0.0.0.0} also didn't work

I am however able to access JBoss console from my laptop using the VPS IP address(http://VPS-IP-Address:9990/console/App.html#home).

Kindly help.

Regards

Ziauddin Syed

Answer (score 0):

The ports 8080 and 8443 were not open on the VPS. Opened them I was able to access my application